# Automatically running code at the start of every C function

Tags: c, function, debugging, gcc, c-preprocessor

I have an almost identical question as [How to add code at the entry of every function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081123/how-to-add-code-at-the-entry-of-every-function) but for **C**:

As I'm maintaining someone else's large undocumented project, I wish to have code similar to

```
static C0UNT_identifier_not_used_anywhere_else = 0;
printf("%s%s:%d#%d", __func__, strrchr(__FILE__,'/'), __LINE__, ++C0UNT_identifier_not_used_anywhere_else);
```

to run on entry of every function, so that I

1. have a log of what calls what, and
2. can tell, on which n<sup>th</sup> call to a function it breaks.

The existing code comprises hundreds of source files, so it is unfeasible to put a macro e.g.

```
#define ENTRY_CODE ...
...
int function() {
  ENTRY_CODE
  ...
}
```

in every function. I am also not using DevStudio, Visual Studio or other compiler providing __cyg_profile_func_enter or such extensions.

Optionally, I'd like to printf the return value of each function on exit in a similar style. Can I do that too?

Comment: It would help to know what compiler you *are* using

Comment: And what debugger you have available.

Comment: @PaulR - He's tagged it GCC - what do you want beyond that?

Comment: @Kevin Vermeer: he also claims that his compiler does not have support for function entry/exit hooks, which gcc does, so it's not 100% clear whether he really is using gcc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have tagged with gcc it has the `-finstrument-functions` option:

> Generate instrumentation calls for entry and exit to functions. ...