# How to get the name, or file and line of caller method?

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, methods, c++11

Is there a way in C++11 (using the latest GCC) to get the name, or the file and line number, of *the method calling the currently executed method* (the caller)?

I want to use this information in an error message when, for example, the following code fails:

```
void SomewhereInMyProgram()
{
    DoSomething(nullptr);
}

void DoSomething(const char* str)
{
    Contract::Requires(str != nullptr);
    // ...
}
```

Currently I have code in place that reports the error as occurring in `DoSomething`. While this is technically true, I'd like it to report the error as occurring in `SomewhereInMyProgram` wherever that may be. That would make my life a whole lot easier!

The solution can use any C++11 features, macro's or GCC specific stuff, but rather not something I have to add at each and every call site.

I think a stacktrace will **not** help me, because I cannot use exception handling. Actually, I'm very limited: it's a freestanding environment where the standard C++ headers are not available. I was hoping for a macro solution of some sort.

---

```
class Contract
{
public:
    static void RequiresImpl(bool condition, const char* expression,
        const char* file, int line);

    #define Requires(condition) RequiresImpl(condition, #condition , \
        __FILE__, __LINE__ )
};
```

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a runtime stacktrace, ie have  a look at this SO question (how they get the stacktrace) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes

Comment: @epatel I am **not** looking for a stacktrace, because I cannot use exception handling. By the way, I am surely not asking the same question as the one you marked duplicate?

Comment: I meant that you should look into the `handler()` function to see how they get the stack trace from there, ie the functions `backtrace()`, `backtrace_symbols()` and `backtrace_symbols_fd()`. Try using them at the same place you want to get the "caller"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the file name and a line number of a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022436/how-to-get-the-file-name-and-a-line-number-of-a-function-call)

Answer (score 6):

Wrap DoSomething in a macro:

```
void DoSomethingImp(char const *, char const *file, char const *line)
{
    // do whatever needed, use file and line to report problems
}

#define DoSomething(x) DoSomethingImp(x, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

**DISCLAIMER:**

This is not the best thing to do, people are screaming on WIN API macros defined this way for either ANSI or UNICODE. But I believe this is the only way if you don't want to change every call to DoSomething.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, the only way to AUTOMATICALLY get information about previous calls is to use a backtrace. This post has a ton of information about doing that:

[How to generate a stacktrace when my gcc C++ app crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes)

Comment: After reading your additional requirements, I think you're going to need to use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081123/how-to-add-code-at-the-entry-of-every-function

Answer (score -5):

In gcc you can use one of the following macros: `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` or `__FUNCTION__` or `__func__`.

Comment: This gives the name of the current function, not the name or line number of the caller function.