# How to get the file name and a line number of a function call?

Tags: c++

I have two functions in different source files:

a.cpp

```
void A()
{
    B();
}
```

b.cpp

```
void B()
{
    std::cout << "B() called from file: " << ??? << " line: " << ??? << std::endl;
}
```

How can I get the file name and line number of the call?

Comment: `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` respectively.

Comment: For C++20: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58556021/5267751

Comment: This should not be a duplicate because it's not sufficient to just use those macros, it's also necessary to "hide the function behind a macro" (see the accepted answer) And that's not the only possible answer, there's another answer in C++20 which would not be appropriate for the other question (see the comment above)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In general you can do this automatically by hiding your function behind a macro call which passes allong the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` values

```
void _B(const char* file, int line) { ... } 
#define B() _B(__FILE__, __LINE__)
```

This is by no means a foolproof solution though.  It's possible for developers to call `_B` directly or for `_B` to be called from generated code, assembly, etc .... where there may be no meaningful file / line number

OP asked for an example with arguments

```
void _C(int p1, char p2, const char* file, int line) { ... } 
#define C(p1, p2) _C(p1, p2, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

Comment: Did you pass file as an int on purpose?

Comment: @kazemakase no, haven't finished coffee yet, making idiot mistakes :(

Comment: and what if the B() function would have other arguments?

Comment: @VitaliusKuchalskis add them into the macro as well and forward them onto the implementation function

Comment: and also... What about constructor macros?

Comment: @VitaliusKuchalskis not sure what you mean by that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean what if the function B() is a constructor of a class B?

Comment: @VitaliusKuchalskis in that case you'd either need `_B` to return an instance of `B` or have a macro that is not the class name.  Or alternative switch from constructors to static creation methods.

Answer (score 0):

code:
`printf("%s(%d)--:",__FILE__,__LINE__);`

reference:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.